# istio virtual service route destination with context path

Tags: kubernetes, istio, servicemesh

I have istio configuration on which the docker container runs jasperreports on tomcat([bitnami jasperreports](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/jasperreports/)). the application itself could be accessed with context path at http://IP:8080/jasperserver.

I am planning to use istio in my kubernetes configuration, expose the service using http gateway and virtual service. can I add context path of "jasperserver" in addition to destination host and port number in virtual service configuration?

here is my current virtualservice configuration

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: http-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default controller
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: jasper-virtual-services  
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - http-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        exact: /report
    
    route:
    - destination:
        host: jasperserver.reporting.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 80
```

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for [rewrites](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#HTTPRewrite)

Something like

```
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        exact: /report
    rewrite:
      uri: /jasperserver
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried that, but it results in "too many redirects"

Comment: @Yuyanto maybe the container does some redirect, but without details I am afraid I can't say anything more specific

Comment: Try adding the same uri but as prefix instead of exact.

Comment: @Yuyanto I suspect there is something wrong with the the app itself. I have tried to reproduce the issue and it works without rewrite,  the problem occurs after you add a rewrite as jesperserver creates some strange path,`/jasperserver/login.html;jsessionid=1537778E913161D7E84D98E200CA3842`, but the rewrite itself works correct.

Comment: @user140547 yes.. if we access the container directly, like localhost:8080, it will automatically redirect to localhost:8080/jasperserver

Comment: @Jakub are you using the same container  from https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/jasperreports/

are you using the same gateway and virtual service i provide?

btw, i run this on GKE.. does that make any difference?

Comment: @Yuyanto I have used bitnami [helm chart](https://bitnami.com/stack/jasperreports/helm) to test that and I also used GKE. I used your gateway and virtual service with   `http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        exact: /report
    rewrite:
      uri: /jasperserver` and  `http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        exact: /report/
    rewrite:
      uri: /jasperserver/` as sometimes the issue was lack of `/` in the end.  `if we access the container directly, like localhost:8080, it will automatically redirect to localhost:8080/jasperserver` that's why istio rewrite does not work.

Comment: ok.. let me try using the chart..
i need to add more sidecar inside the pod, thats why i use the docker image and build the deployment yaml from scratch.. will update on the findings..
thanks in advance @Jakub

Comment: @Yuyanto Note that with rewrite I had the same issue as yours, even if You use helm chart nothing change, as it use the same image.  The only thing worked for me was when I used the exact uri prefix without the rewrite, so just `- match:- uri:
prefix: /jasperserver`.

Comment: @Jakub I actually tested using prefix before changing to exact but not working at my side.. I use google load balancer as the primary ingress.. could that be the reason.. let me try using istio ingress to figure out at least a working config

Comment: @Jakub you are right.. it works normally without any issue if i am using default istio configuration. my mistake was adding another ingress with HTTP type load balancer.
Thankyou very much

Comment: @ChristophRaab sorry i missed out your comment.. and yes, prefix did solve the issue.. 

thanks everyone..